# Retrieve data from SQL Server using wildcard with LIKE

Tags: sql-server, django, wildcard, sql-like, pyodbc

I have a django project that is connected to SQL Server using **pyodbc**.

I am able to connect  and retrieve data.

But the problem is when i tried to filter the data on multiple fields using **WHERE & LIKE** the system crash crash and display the below error.

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'format'

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pyodbc


def connect(request):

    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
        'Server=DESKTOP-LPD1575\\SQLEXPRESS;'
        'Database=testDB;'
        'UID=test;'
        'PWD=test;'

    )
    query = 'n'
    queryid = 3
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    c = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Artist where artistName like  ? or id = ?',('%{0}%','{1}').format(query,queryid))

    print(c)
    return render (request,'connect.html',{"c":c})
```

## connect.html

```
<table align = "center">
<tr align="center">
            <th>id</th>
            <th>FolderNumber</th>
            <th>Folderdate</th>

        </tr>
{% for row in c %}
 <tr align="center">
    <td>{{ row.0 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.2 }}</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be passing a tuple as the second parameter to `cursor.execute()`, using just literal values:

```
c = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Artist WHERE artistName LIKE ? OR id = ?',
    ('%' + query + '%', queryid))
```